# If $A$ is a real $n \times n$ matrix satisfying $A^3 = I$ then Trace of $A$ is always

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a real $3 \times 3$ matrix satisfying $A^3$ = I such that $ A \neq I $   .Then, Trace of A is always

- $0$
- $1$
- $-1$
- $3$

I proceed as follows: from given,
$\min(x)=x-1$ or $x^2+x+1$  or  $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

$\min(x)\ne x-1$ as $A\ne I$

so, $\min(x)=x^2+x+1$ or $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

now, how to proceed after this step

any help would be appreciated

Comment: In title $A^3=A$, but in body $A^3=I$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Hint: eigenvalues of $A^n$ are precisely the $n$th powers of eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @ Wojowu then eigenvalues of A would be 1,$\omega,\omega^2$..

Comment: You know that there is at least one real eigenvalue, since the degree is odd. What can you conclude for minimal polynomial then? What can you conclude for characteristic polynomial then?

Comment: @Ennar i know that x=1 is the only real eigenvalue,then,min(x)$\neq x^2+x+1$ since it gives complex eigenvalues over real field

Comment: @Ennar i have a problem in understanding what you asked.I would be really thankful if you could explain it..

Comment: You already discarded $x-1$ as minimal polynomial and now you know that $x^2 + x + 1$ is not minimial either. Thus, your minimal polynomial is $x^3 - 1$, and it is of degree $3$, same as characteristic polynomial. But you do know how to calculate trace from characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, anihilating polynomial for $A$ is $t^3-1$. So, the possible minimal polynomials are

$m_1(t)=t-1$

$m_2(t)=t^2+t+1$

$m_3(t)=(t-1)(t^2+t+1)$

Discard $m_1(t)$ as $A\neq I$. Discard $m_2(t)$ as $t^2+t+1=0$ gives two complex eigenvalues but where is the third one?

Now,  $m_3(t)=0$ gives eigenvalues as $1$,$\frac{-1\pm i√3}{2}$. So, tr($A$)$=$sum of eigenvalues$=0$.

Comment: @ mathlover;thanks for clear solution

Answer (score 2):

Here are two matrices $A$ with $A^3 = A$:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\qquad A = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since these have diffferent traces, the question does not have a definite answer.

Edit: The matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the desired property (for the edited question) and has trace 0. Hence, if the question is well-posed, the answer must be 0.

Comment: :i have edited the question..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since $A$ is $3 \times 3$, $A$ has exactly 1 or 3 real eigenvalues.

If $A$ has three real eigenvalue, then $\lambda=1$ is the only eignevalue of $A$.
Prove that in this case $A=I$ [Hint Jordan form and $A^3=I$], which is not possible.

Therefore, one of the eigenvalues is real, and the other two are complex. Therefore the eignevalues are ....

Comment: What about an element of SO$(3)$ corresponding to rotation by angle $2\pi/3$ for various axes? All of them have $+1$ as  a simple eigenvalue, and conjugate complex  numbers as other eigenvalues. Example: $A$ is the permutation matrix corresponding to a cyclic permutation of a basis.

Comment: @PVanchinathan And what about them? The point is that $A$ must have exactly one real eigenvalue, which means the other two eigenvalues are $\omega$ adn $\omega^2$.  Then the trace is $$1+\omega+\omega^2=0$$

Comment: @PVanchinathan I don't like to solve assignment questions, that's why i posted a hint: one eigenvalue is real and two complex.....

Comment: Have I misunderstood you? You seem to say  in your post  "a $3\times3$ real matrix $A$ with $A^3=I$ having just one real eigen value should be  $I$". A cyclic permutation matrix of order 3 and size $3\times3$ violates this statement.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Sorry typo, I mean three real eigenvalues :) I meant if $A^3=I$ and $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$ then $A=I$ ,,,

Answer (score 1):

$$A^3=I\iff A^2=A^{-1}$$ If the question is valid for all matrix then with a single example one can answer. Consider the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Calculation gives $$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\text { and } A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ We see then that $A^3=I$ and here the trace is obviously equal to $0$. Hence the answer is $0$.